# DropDown empurra div para baixo

Tags: javascript, dropdown

Tenho um codigo html com JavaScript com um dropDown para estado que exibe a cidade de acordo com esse estado e depois mostra um endereço, a cada seleção ele empurra a div que esta em baixo mais para baixo.

```html
<div class="fisico "  >
<select id="test" name="form_select" onchange="mostrarCidade(this)" style="width: 200px;  text-align: center; text-align-last: center;">
   <option value="0">Estados</option>
   <option value="1">Rio de Janeiro</option>
   <option value="2">Espirito Santo</option>
   <option value="3">Minas Gerais</option>
</select>
<div id="cidadeRio" style="display:none;" style="position:relative;" >
<select id="rio" name="form_rio" onchange="mostrarEndereco(this)" style="width: 200px;text-align: center; text-align-last: center;" >
   <option value="0">Cidade</option>
   <option value="1">ITAPERUNA</option>
   <option value="2">CAMPOS DOS GOYTACAZES</option>
   <option value="3">RIO DAS OSTRAS</option>
   <option value="4">MACAÉ</option>
   <option value="5">SAQUAREMA</option>
   <option value="6">MARICA</option>
   <option value="7">ARARUAMA</option>
   <option value="8">CABO FRIO</option>
   <option value="9">RIO BONITO</option>
   <option value="10">SÃO PEDRO DA ALDEIA</option>
   <option value="11">NOVA FRIBURGO</option>
   <option value="12">PETROPOLIS</option>
   <option value="13">TERESOPOLIS</option>
</select><br>
<div class="ruasRio" style="width: 200px; text-align: center; text-align-last: center;">
<div id="itaperuna" style="display:none;" >AV CARDOSO MOREIRA nº325 - Centro</div>
<div id="campos"style="display:none;">AV 7 DE SETEMBRO nº492 - Centro</div>
<div id="ostras"style="display:none;">AV AMARAL PEIXOTO nº4472 - BALNEARIO REMANSO</div>
<div id="macae"style="display:none;">AV RUI BARBOSA nº663 - Centro</div>
<div id="saquarema"style="display:none;"> RUA PROF FRANCISCO FONSECA nº350 - Bacaxa</div>
<div id="marica"style="display:none;"> PC CONSELHERO MACEDO SOARES nº168 - Centro</div>
<div id="araruama"style="display:none;"> RUA MAJOR FELIX MOREIRA nº107 - Centro</div>
<div id="cabo"style="display:none;"> RUA TEIXEIRA E SOUZA  nº31 - Centro</div>
<div id="bonito"style="display:none;">RUA XV DE NOVEMBRO nº104</div>
<div id="pedro"style="display:none;">RUA DR ANTONIO ALVES nº208/218 - Centro</div>
<div id="friburgo"style="display:none;">AV ALBERTO BRAUNE nº64 - Centro</div>
<div id="petropolis"style="display:none;">RUA DO IMPERADOR nº751 - Centro</div>
<div id="teresopolis"style="display:none;">AV DELFIM MOREIRA nº610 - Centro</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="cidadeEs" style="display:none;" style="position:relative;">
<select id="es" name="form_es" onchange="mostrarEndereco(this)" style="width: 200px;  text-align: center; text-align-last: center; ">
   <option value="14">Cidade</option>
   <option value="15">VILA VELHA</option>
   <option value="16">VITORIA</option>
   <option value="17">SERRA</option>
   <option value="18">CARIACICA</option>
   <option value="19">CACHOEIRO DE ITAPEMIRIM</option>
   <option value="20">GUARAPARI</option>
   <option value="21">SÄO MATEUS</option>
   <option value="22">LINHARES</option>
   <option value="23">ARACRUZ</option>
   <option value="24">COLATINA</option>
   <option value="25">GUACUI</option>
  </select><br>
  <div class="ruasEs" style="width: 200px; text-align: center; text-align-last: center;">
<div id="velha" style="display:none;">AV JERONIMO MONTEIRO nº74 - Centro</div>
<div id="vitoria"style="display:none;">AV PRINCESA ISABEL nº426 - Centro</div>
<div id="serra"style="display:none;">AV JOAO PALACIOS nº300 - Fatima</div>
<div id="cariacica"style="display:none;">Rod. BR 262, KM 5 nº6555 - São Francisco</div>
<div id="itapemirim"style="display:none;">RUA CEL  FRANCISCO BRAGA nº71/73 - Centro</div>
<div id="guarapari"style="display:none;"> RUA EWERSON DE ABREU SODRE nº1 - Muquicaba</div>
<div id="mateus"style="display:none;"> RUA CEL. MATEUS CUNHA nº67 - Centro</div>
<div id="linhares"style="display:none;"> AV GOV JONES SANTOS NEVES nº912 - Centro</div>
<div id="aracruz"style="display:none;">AV VENANCIO FLORES nº1116 - Centro</div>
<div id="colatina"style="display:none;">AV GETULIO VARGAS nº203 - Centro</div>
<div id="guacui"style="display:none;"> PRACA DA BANDEIRA nº1 - Centro</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="cidadeMinas" style="display:none; " style="position:relative;" >
<select id="minas" name="form_minas" onchange="mostrarEndereco(this)" style="width: 200px" style="height: 125px; ">
   <option value="26">Cidade</option>
   <option value="27">BELO HORIZONTE</option>
   <option value="28">RIBEIRAO DAS NEVES</option>
   <option value="29">SANTA LUZIA</option>
   <option value="30">CONTAGEM</option>
   <option value="31">BETIM</option>
   <option value="32">CONSELHEIRO LAFAIETE</option>
   <option value="33">SETE LAGOAS</option>
   <option value="34">BARBACENA</option>
   <option value="35">MONTES CLAROS</option>
   <option value="36">JUIZ DE FORA</option>
   <option value="37">DIVINOPOLIS</option>
   <option value="38">GOVERNADOR VALADARES</option>
   <option value="39">TIMOTEO</option>
   <option value="40">IPATINGA</option>
   </select><br>
  <div class="ruasMinas" style="width: 200px; text-align: center; text-align-last: center;">
<div id="bh" style="display:none;">RUA DOS CARIJOS nº516 - Centro</div>
<div id="neves"style="display:none;">RUA RAIMUNDO NONATO DE SOUZA nº26 - Centro</div>
<div id="luzia"style="display:none;">AV BRASILIA nº2165 - São Benedito</div>
<div id="contagem"style="display:none;">RUA TIRADENTES nº2550 - Bairro Industrial</div>
<div id="betim"style="display:none;">RODOVIA BR 381 FERNÃO DIAS KM 492,6 - São João</div>
<div id="lafaiete"style="display:none;"> RUA DOUTOR MELO VIANA nº10 - Centro</div>
<div id="lagoas"style="display:none;"> AV DEPUTADO EMILIO DE VASCONCELOS COSTA nº34 - Centro</div>
<div id="barbacena"style="display:none;"> RUA QUINZE DE NOVEMBRO nº86 - Centro</div>
<div id="claros"style="display:none;">AV DONATO QUINTINO nº90 - Canelas</div>
<div id="juiz"style="display:none;">RUA MARECHAL DEODORO nº558 - Centro</div>
<div id="divinopolis"style="display:none;"> RUA MOACIR JOSE LEITE nº100 - Santa Clara</div>
<div id="valadares"style="display:none;"> RUA MARECHAL FLORIANO nº824 - Centro</div>
<div id="timoteo"style="display:none;"> ALAMENDA 31 DE OUTUBRO nº115 - Centro Norte</div>
<div id="ipatinga"style="display:none;"> AV 28 DE ABRIL nº187 - Centro</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

function mostrarCidade(select){
   if(select.value==1){
    document.getElementById('cidadeRio').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('cidadeEs').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('cidadeMinas').style.display = "none";
   } else if(select.value==2){
    document.getElementById('cidadeRio').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('cidadeEs').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('cidadeMinas').style.display = "none";
   }else if(select.value==3){
    document.getElementById('cidadeRio').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('cidadeEs').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('cidadeMinas').style.display = "block";
   }else{
    document.getElementById('cidadeRio').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('cidadeEs').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('cidadeMinas').style.display = "none";
}
} 
function mostrarEndereco(select){
   if(select.value==1){
    document.getElementById('itaperuna').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('campos').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('ostras').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('macae').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('saquarema').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('marica').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('araruama').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('cabo').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('bonito').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('pedro').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('friburgo').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('petropolis').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('teresopolis').style.display = "none";
    }  else if(select.value==2){
        document.getElementById('campos').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('itaperuna').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('ostras').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('macae').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('saquarema').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('marica').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('araruama').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('cabo').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('bonito').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('pedro').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('friburgo').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('petropolis').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('teresopolis').style.display = "none";
   }else if(select.value==3){
            document.getElementById('ostras').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('campos').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('itaperuna').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('macae').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('saquarema').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('marica').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('araruama').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('cabo').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('bonito').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('pedro').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('friburgo').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('petropolis').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('teresopolis').style.display = "none";
   }
```

Gostaria de saber como resolver esse problema

Comment: Tenta tirar esse `style="position:relative;"` pois deixa relativo. Creio que seja ele que está fazendo iso.

Comment: Eu ja tentei deixar sem e não funcionou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A única forma que vejo da não empurrar o conteúdo de baixo mais para baixo e fazer o conteúdo abrir por cima do que vem abaixo. Mas como vc vai ver abaixo isso me parece meio estranho... Vai cobrir tudo que vier abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz esse exemplo só para o Rio, vou deixar para vc fazer os outros e aprender como fiz. Mas basicamente precisei colocar `position:absolut` na `div cidade`, e na `div ruas` precisei colocar um cor de background e uma borda que fiz com `box-shadow` para não interferir no *box model*

```js
function mostrarCidade(select) {
    if (select.value == 1) {
        document.getElementById('cidadeRio').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('cidadeEs').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('cidadeMinas').style.display = "none";
    } else if (select.value == 2) {
        document.getElementById('cidadeRio').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('cidadeEs').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('cidadeMinas').style.display = "none";
    } else if (select.value == 3) {
        document.getElementById('cidadeRio').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('cidadeEs').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('cidadeMinas').style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('cidadeRio').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('cidadeEs').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('cidadeMinas').style.display = "none";
    }
}

function mostrarEndereco(select) {
    if (select.value == 1) {
        document.getElementById('itaperuna').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('campos').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('ostras').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('macae').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('saquarema').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('marica').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('araruama').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('cabo').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('bonito').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('pedro').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('friburgo').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('petropolis').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('teresopolis').style.display = "none";
    } else if (select.value == 2) {
        document.getElementById('campos').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('itaperuna').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('ostras').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('macae').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('saquarema').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('marica').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('araruama').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('cabo').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('bonito').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('pedro').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('friburgo').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('petropolis').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('teresopolis').style.display = "none";
    } else if (select.value == 3) {
        document.getElementById('ostras').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('campos').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('itaperuna').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('macae').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('saquarema').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('marica').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('araruama').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('cabo').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('bonito').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('pedro').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('friburgo').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('petropolis').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('teresopolis').style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="fisico ">
    <select id="test" name="form_select" onchange="mostrarCidade(this)" style="width: 200px;  text-align: center; text-align-last: center;">
        <option value="0">Estados</option>
        <option value="1">Rio de Janeiro</option>
        <option value="2">Espirito Santo</option>
        <option value="3">Minas Gerais</option>
    </select>
    <div id="cidadeRio" style="display:none; position:absolute;">
        <select id="rio" name="form_rio" onchange="mostrarEndereco(this)" style="width: 200px;text-align: center; text-align-last: center;">
            <option value="0">Cidade</option>
            <option value="1">ITAPERUNA</option>
            <option value="2">CAMPOS DOS GOYTACAZES</option>
            <option value="3">RIO DAS OSTRAS</option>
            <option value="4">MACAÉ</option>
            <option value="5">SAQUAREMA</option>
            <option value="6">MARICA</option>
            <option value="7">ARARUAMA</option>
            <option value="8">CABO FRIO</option>
            <option value="9">RIO BONITO</option>
            <option value="10">SÃO PEDRO DA ALDEIA</option>
            <option value="11">NOVA FRIBURGO</option>
            <option value="12">PETROPOLIS</option>
            <option value="13">TERESOPOLIS</option>
        </select><br>
        <div class="ruasRio" style="width: 200px; text-align: center; text-align-last: center; background-color: #fff; box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px black">
            <div id="itaperuna" style="display:none;">AV CARDOSO MOREIRA nº325 - Centro</div>
            <div id="campos" style="display:none;">AV 7 DE SETEMBRO nº492 - Centro</div>
            <div id="ostras" style="display:none;">AV AMARAL PEIXOTO nº4472 - BALNEARIO REMANSO</div>
            <div id="macae" style="display:none;">AV RUI BARBOSA nº663 - Centro</div>
            <div id="saquarema" style="display:none;"> RUA PROF FRANCISCO FONSECA nº350 - Bacaxa</div>
            <div id="marica" style="display:none;"> PC CONSELHERO MACEDO SOARES nº168 - Centro</div>
            <div id="araruama" style="display:none;"> RUA MAJOR FELIX MOREIRA nº107 - Centro</div>
            <div id="cabo" style="display:none;"> RUA TEIXEIRA E SOUZA nº31 - Centro</div>
            <div id="bonito" style="display:none;">RUA XV DE NOVEMBRO nº104</div>
            <div id="pedro" style="display:none;">RUA DR ANTONIO ALVES nº208/218 - Centro</div>
            <div id="friburgo" style="display:none;">AV ALBERTO BRAUNE nº64 - Centro</div>
            <div id="petropolis" style="display:none;">RUA DO IMPERADOR nº751 - Centro</div>
            <div id="teresopolis" style="display:none;">AV DELFIM MOREIRA nº610 - Centro</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cidadeEs" style="display:none; position:relative;">
        <select id="es" name="form_es" onchange="mostrarEndereco(this)" style="width: 200px;  text-align: center; text-align-last: center; ">
            <option value="14">Cidade</option>
            <option value="15">VILA VELHA</option>
            <option value="16">VITORIA</option>
            <option value="17">SERRA</option>
            <option value="18">CARIACICA</option>
            <option value="19">CACHOEIRO DE ITAPEMIRIM</option>
            <option value="20">GUARAPARI</option>
            <option value="21">SÄO MATEUS</option>
            <option value="22">LINHARES</option>
            <option value="23">ARACRUZ</option>
            <option value="24">COLATINA</option>
            <option value="25">GUACUI</option>
        </select><br>
        <div class="ruasEs" style="width: 200px; text-align: center; text-align-last: center;">
            <div id="velha" style="display:none;">AV JERONIMO MONTEIRO nº74 - Centro</div>
            <div id="vitoria" style="display:none;">AV PRINCESA ISABEL nº426 - Centro</div>
            <div id="serra" style="display:none;">AV JOAO PALACIOS nº300 - Fatima</div>
            <div id="cariacica" style="display:none;">Rod. BR 262, KM 5 nº6555 - São Francisco</div>
            <div id="itapemirim" style="display:none;">RUA CEL FRANCISCO BRAGA nº71/73 - Centro</div>
            <div id="guarapari" style="display:none;"> RUA EWERSON DE ABREU SODRE nº1 - Muquicaba</div>
            <div id="mateus" style="display:none;"> RUA CEL. MATEUS CUNHA nº67 - Centro</div>
            <div id="linhares" style="display:none;"> AV GOV JONES SANTOS NEVES nº912 - Centro</div>
            <div id="aracruz" style="display:none;">AV VENANCIO FLORES nº1116 - Centro</div>
            <div id="colatina" style="display:none;">AV GETULIO VARGAS nº203 - Centro</div>
            <div id="guacui" style="display:none;"> PRACA DA BANDEIRA nº1 - Centro</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cidadeMinas" style="display:none; position:relative; ">
        <select id="minas" name="form_minas" onchange="mostrarEndereco(this)" style="width: 200px" >
            <option value="26">Cidade</option>
            <option value="27">BELO HORIZONTE</option>
            <option value="28">RIBEIRAO DAS NEVES</option>
            <option value="29">SANTA LUZIA</option>
            <option value="30">CONTAGEM</option>
            <option value="31">BETIM</option>
            <option value="32">CONSELHEIRO LAFAIETE</option>
            <option value="33">SETE LAGOAS</option>
            <option value="34">BARBACENA</option>
            <option value="35">MONTES CLAROS</option>
            <option value="36">JUIZ DE FORA</option>
            <option value="37">DIVINOPOLIS</option>
            <option value="38">GOVERNADOR VALADARES</option>
            <option value="39">TIMOTEO</option>
            <option value="40">IPATINGA</option>
        </select><br>
        <div class="ruasMinas" style="width: 200px; text-align: center; text-align-last: center;">
            <div id="bh" style="display:none;">RUA DOS CARIJOS nº516 - Centro</div>
            <div id="neves" style="display:none;">RUA RAIMUNDO NONATO DE SOUZA nº26 - Centro</div>
            <div id="luzia" style="display:none;">AV BRASILIA nº2165 - São Benedito</div>
            <div id="contagem" style="display:none;">RUA TIRADENTES nº2550 - Bairro Industrial</div>
            <div id="betim" style="display:none;">RODOVIA BR 381 FERNÃO DIAS KM 492,6 - São João</div>
            <div id="lafaiete" style="display:none;"> RUA DOUTOR MELO VIANA nº10 - Centro</div>
            <div id="lagoas" style="display:none;"> AV DEPUTADO EMILIO DE VASCONCELOS COSTA nº34 - Centro</div>
            <div id="barbacena" style="display:none;"> RUA QUINZE DE NOVEMBRO nº86 - Centro</div>
            <div id="claros" style="display:none;">AV DONATO QUINTINO nº90 - Canelas</div>
            <div id="juiz" style="display:none;">RUA MARECHAL DEODORO nº558 - Centro</div>
            <div id="divinopolis" style="display:none;"> RUA MOACIR JOSE LEITE nº100 - Santa Clara</div>
            <div id="valadares" style="display:none;"> RUA MARECHAL FLORIANO nº824 - Centro</div>
            <div id="timoteo" style="display:none;"> ALAMENDA 31 DE OUTUBRO nº115 - Centro Norte</div>
            <div id="ipatinga" style="display:none;"> AV 28 DE ABRIL nº187 - Centro</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt repudiandae sit optio dolorum, delectus impedit magni atque doloremque eos dolores ratione minima sapiente saepe placeat quam, facilis nisi autem asperiores.</p>
```

Comment: Funcionou muito Obrigada!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Você é demais!!!

Comment: @vanessa sem problemas, legal que deu certo ai ;)

Answer (score 0):

Olá Vanessa seja bem vinda ao Stack Overflow. 
Primeiramente seu código não está funcionando aqui pois está com alguns erros(não sei se ocorreu quando você colou o código para demonstrar). Atente-se muito a escrever um código legível pois assim fica mais fácil encontrar erros ou falhas que venham a acontecer.
Dentre as coisas que você deve estar atenta estão:

- Falta de espaço entre a classe e o id
  `id="saquarema"style="display:none;"` ficaria `id="saquarema" style="display:none;"`
- Duplicação do style:
  `style="display:none;" style="position:relative;"` deve-se utilizar apenas um `style` com seus estilos separados por `;` assim `style="display:none; position:relative;"`. Ainda nesse ponto para facilitar sua vida recomendo fortemente que utilize classes pois assim com uma classe você controla vários elementos sem ter que ficar reescrevendo o `style`, por exemplo esse codigo:

  ```
  <div class="ruasRio" style="width: 200px; text-align: center; text-align-last: center;">
      <div id="itaperuna" style="display:none;" >AV CARDOSO MOREIRA nº325 - Centro</div>
      <div id="campos" style="display:none;">AV 7 DE SETEMBRO nº492 - Centro</div>
      <div id="ostras" style="display:none;">AV AMARAL PEIXOTO nº4472 - BALNEARIO REMANSO</div>
      <div id="macae" style="display:none;">AV RUI BARBOSA nº663 - Centro</div>
      <div id="saquarema" style="display:none;"> RUA PROF FRANCISCO FONSECA nº350 - Bacaxa</div>
      <div id="marica" style="display:none;"> PC CONSELHERO MACEDO SOARES nº168 - Centro</div>
      <div id="araruama" style="display:none;"> RUA MAJOR FELIX MOREIRA nº107 - Centro</div>
      <div id="cabo" style="display:none;"> RUA TEIXEIRA E SOUZA  nº31 - Centro</div>
      <div id="bonito" style="display:none;">RUA XV DE NOVEMBRO nº104</div>
      <div id="pedro" style="display:none;">RUA DR ANTONIO ALVES nº208/218 - Centro</div>
      <div id="friburgo" style="display:none;">AV ALBERTO BRAUNE nº64 - Centro</div>
      <div id="petropolis" style="display:none;">RUA DO IMPERADOR nº751 - Centro</div>
      <div id="teresopolis" style="display:none;">AV DELFIM MOREIRA nº610 - Centro</div>
  </div>
  ```

Ficaria assim:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        .ruasRio {
            width: 200px;
            text-align: center;
            text-align-last: center;
        }
        .ruasRio > div {
            display: none;
        }


    </style>
</head>


    <div class="ruasRio">
        <div id="itaperuna">AV CARDOSO MOREIRA nº325 - Centro</div>
        <div id="campos">AV 7 DE SETEMBRO nº492 - Centro</div>
        <div id="ostras">AV AMARAL PEIXOTO nº4472 - BALNEARIO REMANSO</div>
        <div id="macae">AV RUI BARBOSA nº663 - Centro</div>
        <div id="saquarema"> RUA PROF FRANCISCO FONSECA nº350 - Bacaxa</div>
        <div id="marica"> PC CONSELHERO MACEDO SOARES nº168 - Centro</div>
        <div id="araruama"> RUA MAJOR FELIX MOREIRA nº107 - Centro</div>
        <div id="cabo"> RUA TEIXEIRA E SOUZA  nº31 - Centro</div>
        <div id="bonito">RUA XV DE NOVEMBRO nº104</div>
        <div id="pedro">RUA DR ANTONIO ALVES nº208/218 - Centro</div>
        <div id="friburgo">AV ALBERTO BRAUNE nº64 - Centro</div>
        <div id="petropolis">RUA DO IMPERADOR nº751 - Centro</div>
        <div id="teresopolis">AV DELFIM MOREIRA nº610 - Centro</div>
    </div>
```

- E por último mas não menos importante a identação(acho que é esse o nome), essa 'técnica' nada mais é do que apertar a tecla `tab` para nivelar o seu código sempre que abrir uma tag e for adicionar filhos nela, por exemplo esse código é mais difícil encontrar o fechamento da div `.ruasEs`:

  ```
  <div class="ruasEs" style="width: 200px; text-align: center; text-align-last: center;">
  <div id="velha" style="display:none;">AV JERONIMO MONTEIRO nº74 - Centro</div>
  <div id="vitoria" style="display:none;">AV PRINCESA ISABEL nº426 - Centro</div>
  <div id="serra" style="display:none;">AV JOAO PALACIOS nº300 - Fatima</div>
  <div id="cariacica" style="display:none;">Rod. BR 262, KM 5 nº6555 - São Francisco</div>
  <div id="itapemirim" style="display:none;">RUA CEL  FRANCISCO BRAGA nº71/73 - Centro</div>
  <div id="guarapari" style="display:none;"> RUA EWERSON DE ABREU SODRE nº1 - Muquicaba</div>
  <div id="mateus" style="display:none;"> RUA CEL. MATEUS CUNHA nº67 - Centro</div>
  <div id="linhares" style="display:none;"> AV GOV JONES SANTOS NEVES nº912 - Centro</div>
  <div id="aracruz" style="display:none;">AV VENANCIO FLORES nº1116 - Centro</div>
  <div id="colatina" style="display:none;">AV GETULIO VARGAS nº203 - Centro</div>
  <div id="guacui" style="display:none;"> PRACA DA BANDEIRA nº1 - Centro</div>
  </div>
  ```

Do que esse:

```
  <div class="ruasEs" style="width: 200px; text-align: center; text-align-last: center;">
      <div id="velha" style="display:none;">AV JERONIMO MONTEIRO nº74 - Centro</div>
      <div id="vitoria" style="display:none;">AV PRINCESA ISABEL nº426 - Centro</div>
      <div id="serra" style="display:none;">AV JOAO PALACIOS nº300 - Fatima</div>
      <div id="cariacica" style="display:none;">Rod. BR 262, KM 5 nº6555 - São Francisco</div>
      <div id="itapemirim" style="display:none;">RUA CEL  FRANCISCO BRAGA nº71/73 - Centro</div>
      <div id="guarapari" style="display:none;"> RUA EWERSON DE ABREU SODRE nº1 - Muquicaba</div>
      <div id="mateus" style="display:none;"> RUA CEL. MATEUS CUNHA nº67 - Centro</div>
      <div id="linhares" style="display:none;"> AV GOV JONES SANTOS NEVES nº912 - Centro</div>
      <div id="aracruz" style="display:none;">AV VENANCIO FLORES nº1116 - Centro</div>
      <div id="colatina" style="display:none;">AV GETULIO VARGAS nº203 - Centro</div>
      <div id="guacui" style="display:none;"> PRACA DA BANDEIRA nº1 - Centro</div>
  </div>
```

Dessa forma fica mais fácil perceber se você esqueceu de fechar alguma div que pode estar ocasionando o erro que você falou.
Sei que ficou grande essa resposta e pode acabar não ajudando no que você perguntou, mas esses são conceitos que vão te ajudar a vida toda no ramo de programação independente da linguagem.
E pra fechar fiz um exemplo do seu código utilizando o que falei logo acima e deixei [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/ot4y16fd/) para você fazer uma comparação, e acabei que não consegui encontrar o erro que disse depois de fazer essa organização.

Comment: Valeu você me ensinou todo que meu professor já tinha me ensinado.